# Eclipse short key for to and fro function

Tags: java, eclipse

How can we achieve  to and fro navigation in eclipse editor? ctr+q is taking us to last edited point.

Comment: Alt+Left and Alt+Right?

Comment: @Shree if you got right answer to your question then, accept the answer using tick mark on left of the anwser

Answer (score 0):

F3 to get inside the function.
Alt + left to get back to the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Left arrow and Alt+Right arrow